# How to select a div#id that it's inside an iframe (from inside a plugin method)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-selectors, lightbox

I am trying to make bigger a lightbox depending its content, i just need to select div#id and if length > 0 then i know i need to make box bigger:

This is the method of the plugin that actually appends the iframe HTML into the lightbox window (the div#id is in the iframe contents)

```
  appendhtml: function(obj, width, height, mode) {
    if (typeof mode !== 'undefined') {
      this.changemode(mode);
    }

    this.resize(width + 30, height + 20);

    this.esqueleto.background.bind('complete', $.proxy(function() {
      this.esqueleto.background.removeClass(this.options.name+'-loading');
      this.esqueleto.html.append(obj);
      console.log('19:14');
      console.log(obj);
      console.log(obj.contents().find('#bookingEngine').html());
      console.log(obj.find('#bookingEngine').html());
      console.log($(obj).html());
      console.log($(obj).contents().find('#bookingEngine').html());  /*All my hopes where here*/
      console.log($('#bookingEngine').length);
      console.log(this.esqueleto.html.find('iframe').length);
      console.log(this.esqueleto.html.find('iframe').contents().find('#bookingEngine').length);
    }, this));
  }
```

And this is what my console.log LOG

```
19:14 
jquery...tbox.js (línea 679)[iframe#IF_1332866297227]
jquery...tbox.js (línea 680) null
jquery...tbox.js (línea 681) null
jquery...tbox.js (línea 682) (an empty string)
jquery...tbox.js (línea 683) null
jquery...tbox.js (línea 684) 0
jquery...tbox.js (línea 685) 1
jquery...tbox.js (línea 686) 0
```

how can i reach `$('#bookingEngine')` ? it's inside the iframe ( jquery...tbox.js (línea 685) 1 ) wich i was able to select

Comment: just do `console.log($('#bookingEngine'));`

Comment: @3nigma that would return 0 :(

Comment: are you wrapping the code inside the ready handler? `$(function(){/*your code*/});`? is there an element present in the DOM with the id=`bookingEngine` at the time you call the plugin code

Comment: try `console.log($("iframe").contents().find("#bookingEngine"))`, you can give an id to the iframe and do `console.log($("iframeID").contents().find("#bookingEngine"))`

Comment: have you tried what is `obj`, do `console.log(obj)` inside the plugin code and see where it points to

Comment: @3nigma i have posted all this console.log; unfortunatelly .contents().find() alredy tried.. I can't do the ID because is a random id time() based...

Comment: @3nigma - please post your comment as an answer, as this is the way to go.

Comment: @EliranMalka that really didnt seem to solve the OP's problem so im not gonna post it as answer apparently he is having some scoping issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution are correct, i think that the problem might be that the iframe is on a different  domain an for this reason you can't control that. Read [here](http://www.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/)

This is from the documentation of contents()

> The .contents() method can also be used to get the content document of
>   an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page.

Comment: The iframe has a relative path... so it is in the same domain; if you want to test; please click the bookgin blue button on the top right of the page goo.gl/NYGAv I think the problem is in the obj variable @Nicola Peluchatti

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet everything should work, my only idea is that  since `$(obj).html()` si an empty string, the iframe content hasn't loaded yet when that function is called